# MockMvc not getting injected in integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

MockMvc isn't getting injected, I was performing integration test for my controllers, but the whole thing keeps failing, below is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IntegrationTest {
   @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testCreateRetrieveWithMockMVC() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/etl/processAll/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mockMvcBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder]: Factory method 'mockMvcBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder]: Factory method 'mockMvcBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
```

From whatever I've read `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` solves the above issue, however, that isn't happening. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Additionally I'm getting this as well:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/D579729/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletContextInitializerBeans.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/D579729/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError rings that you have wrong versions of Spring libraries.

Comment: Actually on the contrary spring says that I've more than one version (see the edits)